# How to open a 'File' type file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, file

```
import os
os.startfile('C:\\Some Location\\file.file')
```

When I am trying to run the above code the code gives an error as follows:-
**FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**

While for the same location this code works perfectly for files with '.txt' extension.
For eg,

```
import os
os.startfile('C:\\Some Location\\file.txt')
```

This runs perfectly and opens the file.

Please help me solve this issue, I think I am using the wrong extension for the file. The type of file is 'File'.

Comment: If Windows is saying the type is just 'File', I think that means it has no extension - try 'file' as the name.  Or turn off the stupid Windows feature that hides the actual names of your files from you...

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for `os.startfile`: `Start a file with its associated application.`

Windows must have an association between the extension `.file` and some software. If not, Windows does not know what software to use.

Your `.txt` file is open in Notepad (or other), which is associated to the `.txt` extension files.

To add an association:

- you could create a `.file` file somewhere on your system.
- Then right click on it, and select `Open with`.
- Select which software should handle `.file` extensions, check the "Always use this application for this type" (or something similar, I do not have a Windows to check).

Then next time you try to use `os.startfile()`, it will open the `file.file` with the chosen application.